# Using FD_SET and select with serial port

Tags: windows, sockets, serial-port

I am new to serial port programming and sockets so please be gentle :)

I am using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7. I am trying to receive a packet from the serial port (there is a USB Digi XStick inserted that connects with a remote device). I first use WriteFile to send out the initial packet and this operation completes successfully. When I call select I get Error 10038 "An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket".

Here is the relevant code:

```
char szCodedPort[20];
sprintf(szCodedPort, "\\\\.\\COM%d",3); //manually set for testing purposes
HANDLE fileHandle =  CreateFileA(szCodedPort, 
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
    NULL, 
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

fd_set readfds;
int fd;
fd = _open_osfhandle((long)fileHandle, O_RDONLY);
FD_ZERO(&readfds);
FD_SET(fd, &readfds);       

WSAData WSA_Data;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&WSA_Data);    

res = select(fd,&readfds,NULL,NULL, &waitlen);

WSACleanup();
```

I think my problem is with fd, but I'm not sure how to fix it. What can I use to pass to FD_SET that will represent the serial port so that select will stop generating an error message when it uses readfds? Or am I not even in the right zip code with this one?

Comment: I don't think Windows supports `select()`ing on generic file descriptors (i.e: non-socket file descriptors). You probably have to `WaitForSingleObject()` or `WaitForMultipleObjects()` or something...

Comment: That is one way to do it. Open the serial port in overlapped mode and then use either Overlapped I/O, an I/O Completion Port, or `WaitCommEvent()` to receive notifications when the serial port has data available. Otherwise, you have to poll the port status manually using either `GetCommMask()` or `ClearCommError()`.